# Process files from postman or UI in Node JS, without storing them in local storage

Tags: node.js, multer, data-extraction, file-processing

I am using multer npm library to read files from postman and I am getting the file and its details in my node js code(checked via logging req.file), but my concern is I don't want the file to get stored in my local machine, I just want to extract the data from the file and process further for my requirements.
Is this possible or anyone can suggest me some solutions to this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I read multer libraries, it streams the uploaded file in the disk, and then it processes the file.

If you only want to use the properties like mime/type or originalfilename of the file you can use multer and in the storage options after getting the uploaded file properties, use **cb(null, false)** to prevent storing the file, but if you want to process the file, you can remove it from the disk after your process is done.

Comment: Thank you, will do the same as suggested